# Youtube API Overlay Play Button size off when using setSize

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

When looking at my video player app yesterday morning, I noticed some odd behavior on the AS3 Chromeless player.

When using the setSize function as documented in the API, the giant play button that overlays the video is now suddenly becoming very large, not even close to the dimensions specified.  However, once the play button is clicked, the video player itself is fine.  This is throwing off all of the positioning in my app, and looks terrible.

I assume something changed on the Chromeless Player, but I need to get this to work sooner rather than later.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue / does anyone have a work around?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you set the size, force a redraw. Its gonna do that when you click it, and apparently, in your case, doesn't.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, because after the video ends, the button reappears at the same size, even after I remove / redraw the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5236) for Youtube. People seem to be clamoring for a fix, although Google has not been very responsive.